# Update statement in SQL process

Tags: sql, sql-update

I just want to know, how the update statement works? Like, what does SQL do during the update statement? I'm currently understanding the following script.

```
UPDATE Employees
SET
   EmployeeLeaves -= 1,
   IsOnLeave = CASE WHEN (EmployeeLeaves > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE
   EmployeeNo = 2000;
```

In the `IsOnLeave` statement, does this mean that if the "previous" `EmployeeLeaves` is greater than 1 then the `IsOnleave` will be updated to 1?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **yes** it will get 1 or 0 but most sql implementations would use the value of EmployeeLeaves before the update before the setting of the new value. It seems reasonable since the operation in atomic.

Comment: why do you say "most"? That is part of the SQL standard, right?

Comment: I would assume so. I don't know for certain

Comment: @Thilo: What the SQL standard says is one thing, but SQL implementations are know to diverge from the standard in many and varied ways, hence the tendency to attach "most SQL implementations" to any advice regarding SQL syntax and semantics.

Comment: @Marcelo: I can see that with most features. But in this case the exact behaviour must be pretty much set in stone.

Comment: @Thilo: I wasn't *agreeing* with the use of the qualifier, just explaining it. I responded because your comment implied that being in the SQL standard is enough to assume that a feature will work in any implementation, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but not quite, right. The IsOnLeave column will be updated no matter what; it will become 1 if EmployeeLeaves > 0, otherwise 0. But yes, it is the value of `EmployeeLeaves` of the original record (before the update) that is considered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything on the right hand side of an assignment in an SQL UPDATE refers to the value of the record *before* the update.